# how to bold selected input text to bold

Tags: javascript

I am writing a text (or character) converting program and I am having hard time with some features. so, I am trying how to bold the first input text to print I have very short knowledge on javascript and css so it is hard to bold ONLY the first input text

here is my code

```
"DAD": function(s){ return s.toUpperCase().replace(/[\.\?!]/g, ',').replace(/^.|(,\s+.)/g,  function($1) { return $1.toLowerCase(); }); },
```

in this case I want to change `$1.toLowerCase()` to bold but whenever I try `$1.bold()` it only appears to be `<b> (first input text) </b>` on the screen(webpage) how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just do something like this?

```
function(s){ 
    return s[0].toUpperCase().bold()+s.substring(1,s.length).toLowerCase(); 
}
```

This will uppercase & bold the first character and ensure the rest are lowercase.  Is that what you were trying to do?  It seems to work fine in the console (adding  tags around the first character - you might need to tweak your css, especially if using some kind of reset or something)

```
b {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: if I add that code it shows this " <b>G</b>function toLowerCase() { [native code] } " :(